# Test intersection between two triangles sharing a vertex

Tags: collision-detection, computational-geometry

If I know two triangles in R³ shares just one vertex, how can I know if their intersection is greater than just that vertex? I.e., how can I know if they cross inside each other having a line segment as intersection?

Answer (score 1):

Compute the direction vector of the intersection of the two planes containing the triangles. You can obtain it as the cross-product of the normals to the planes, themselves cross-products of two sides.

Then the signs of the dot products of this vector with the bissectrices of the two triangles at the common vertex tells you if the triangles are on the same side of the common vertex or not.